# Find a basis and the dimension of the subspace of $P_4$ spanned by $\{2-x^2 , 2x^3 -3x+1, 2x+3,4\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I feel very lost. Can someone help me find out what I am doing wrong here.

$S = \{ 2-x^2, 2x^3-3x+1, 2x+3, 4\}$

Standard basis for $P_4$ is $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$

$p_1 = 2-x^2\\
p_2 = 2x^3-3x+1\\
p_3 = 2x+3\\
p_4 = 4\\
p_5 = 0\\
$

$0 = a_1p_1 + a_2p_2 + a_3p_3 + a_4p_4 + a_5p_5 = (2a_1 + a_2 +3a_3 +4a_4) + (-3a_2 + 2a_3)x + (-a_1)x^2 + (2a_2)x^3 + (0)x^4$

$2a_1 + a_2 +3a_3 + 4a_4$

$-3a_2 + 2a_3$

$-a_1$

$2a_2$

$0$

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
            2 &1 &3 &4\\
            0&-3& 2 &0\\ 
           -1& 0& 0& 0\\ 
            0& 2& 0& 0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2\\
a_3\\
a_4\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\end{bmatrix}$$

Then I row reduce to get:

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\&1\\&&1\\&&&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Meaning that all nonzero rows of $B$ are a basis for the row space of $A$?
That is, they form a basis for the subspace spanned by $A$?

$v_1 = (1,0,0,0) \ ; \ v_2= (0,1,0,0) \ ; \ v_3= (0,0,1,0) \ ; \ v_4= (0,0,0,0,1)$ make the basis.

Comment: I took a shot at formatting your work.  Please look it over and correct it if I have misunderstood something, or changed the meaning.  Here is a guide to formating latex....https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It looks good to me, I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis is any linearly independent subset of vectors that spans the space.

Choose sufficiently many columns from $A$ such that they are linearly independent and span the space.

If you can row reduce $A$ into $B$ then your 4 vectors are linearly independent.  Hence, you need all 4 column vectors of $A$ to form your basis.

Comment: Okay, so my work is correct. The row reduction gave me the identity matrix for a 4x4. All of the 4 elements in that are independent correct? Also the dimension is 4 because no 2 rows are multiples of eachother correct?

Comment: Right, if you had a dependency, then you would have row-reduced some number row to 0.  Count the number of pivots to find the dimension of the subspace.

Comment: So the dimension is 4 because there are 4 pivots.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach, Let
$$
S = \{p_3(x),p_2(x),p_1(x),p_0(x)\} = \{ 2x^3-3x+1, 2-x^2, 2x+3, 4\}
$$
and note that $p_0$ is a constant function, so using just $\{p_0\}$ as a basis, you can span all polynomials of degree zero (constant functions).

Adding in $p_1$, with the basis $\{p_1, p_0\}$ you can span all linear polynomials. For example,
$$
ax + b 
 = \frac{a}{2} (2x+3) + b - \frac{3a}{2}
 = \frac{a}{2} p_1(x) + \frac{2b - 3a}{8} p_0(x)
$$
Analogously, since the basis $\{p_1, p_0\}$ generates all lines, the basis $\{p_2, p_1, p_0\}$ will generate all parabolas and $\{p_3, p_2 p_1, p_0\}$ will generate all cubics.

Note that since all elements in $S$ are linearly independent (since each has a different degree), the dimension of the space spanned by $S$ is $|S|=4$.

Comment: Is my approach the same as this just a longer way around. I ended up finding 4 linearly independent elements.

Comment: @Aeryes No, not quite. You need a basis for its _column space_, not its row space. If you delete the last element of $S$, $A$ only has three columns, so the elements of the row space won’t even have the right number of elements!